# Add MauiContext to Prism DI container in dotnet MAUI app

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, prism, maui

We have the following code in CreateMauiApp. We are trying to add a MauiContext object to the container so it is available in ViewModels via DI

```
 public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
 {
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    // register types code etc
    MauiApp mauiApp = builder.Build();
    var mauiContext = new MauiContext(mauiApp.Services);
    builder.Services.AddSingleton(mauiContext);
    return mauiApp; 
 }
```

We are however unable to add mauiContext to the DryIoc container as the code
throws an exception saying that the mauicontext type has not been registered. However
we only get the mauicontext object after the registration of types has been done.
Is it possible to get an instance of the container registry somehow? The below is not working

```
    var container = ContainerLocator.Container;
    var registry = container.Resolve<IContainerRegistry>();
    var mauiContext = new MauiContext(mauiApp.Services);
    registry.RegisterInstance(mauiContext);
```

Comment: Does the following answer your question? Services can be accessed via the `IServiceProvicer`: [How Get Service aka Resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75278334/add-mauicontext-to-prism-di-container-in-dotnet-maui-app). As that answer shows, can be injected in any constructor using parameter `(IServiceProvicer provider).` I think you'll need to register the class containing that constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can postpone the creation of the singleton instance to when it is actually injected:

```
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();

// this won't be null anymore when we actually use it
MauiCountext mauiContext = null;
builder.Services.AddSingleton( () => mauiContext );

MauiApp mauiApp = builder.Build();
mauiContext = new MauiContext(mauiApp.Services);
return mauiApp;
```